# Issue with scala object companion and trait

Tags: scala, class, object, traits

i am trying to do something like this in scala so that the Category class receives its attributes by parameters but i get the following error:

```
object creation impossible, since method apply in trait ModelCompanion of type => asd.Category is not defined
  object Category extends ModelCompanion[Category] {
         ^
one error found
```

Code here:

```
object asd {

  trait ModelCompanion[M <: Model[M]] {
    def apply: M
  }

  trait Model[M <: Model[M]] {
    var id: Int = 0
  }

  object Category extends ModelCompanion[Category] {
    def apply(name: String): Category = new Category(name)
  }

  class Category(var name: String) extends Model[Category] {
  // Do something with name
  }

}
```

I am new to scala so if you could give me some guidance on this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelCompanion` defines an abstract method `apply` without any arguments (or argument lists). In `Category` you define an `apply` method that takes an argument of type `String`. That's not an implementation of the abstract method because it doesn't accept the same number and types of arguments. Therefore `Category` does not provide a suitable definition of `ModelCompanion`'s abstract `apply` method and therefore can not be instantiated.

Depending on the behavior you want, you should either change the definition of `ModelCompanion.apply` to `def apply(name: String): M` or introduce another type argument and use that as the argument type.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly:

```scala
def apply:M
//and 
def apply(name:String):M
//are not the same methods

//if you try define it with override modifier
override def apply(name: String): Category = new Category(name)

//it will expose this fact to you with error:
//method apply overrides nothing.
//Note: the super classes of object Category 
//      contain the following, non final members named apply:
//def apply: ammonite.$sess.cmd8.asd.Category

//You need to define `ModelCompanion` with appriopriate `apply`

trait ModelCompanion[M <: Model[M]] {
  def apply(name:String): M
}

// or override properly current (argumentless) one  
object Category extends ModelCompanion[Category] { 
  override def apply: Category = new Category("Category" + Random.nextInt())
}
```